# Example of a measure on $\mathcal{P}(X)$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Is there an example of a set $X$ and a measure $\mu$ on $\mathcal{P}(X)$ (collection of all the the subsets of $X$) such that $\mu(X)=1$ and $\mu(\{x\})=0$ for all $x$ in $X$?

At first I thought it's obvious that there should be such a measure but then I couldn't find any. Now I have a feeling it has something to do with being countably additive. but I don't know why.

Is there any lemma or theorem that shows there can't be any measure with this property?

Comment: How about $X=[0,1]$ with Lebesgue measure?

Comment: @emma I need something defined on all the subsets of X

Comment: Well, it's at least consistent without the axiom of choice, and with assuming large cardinal axioms are consistent (with strong enough axioms allowing you to keep the axiom of choice), that there is a measure on $\cal P(\Bbb R)$ measuring all sets and extends the Lebesgue measure (without choice it is even possible that it *is* the Lebesgue measure). But since you're allowing arbitrary measures, I'm not entirely sure.

Comment: This is not an easy problem - it seems the existence is pretty fundamentally tied to your set theory. https://mathoverflow.net/questions/103583/finite-measure-on-the-power-set

Comment: @Parto Theorem 5.6 in John Oxtoby's _Measure and Category_ (attributed to Ulam) shows that such a measure does not exist (assuming the axiom of choice). If you only require your "measure" to be finitely additive, however, such a measure does exist: Let $U$ be a non-principal ultrafilter over $[0,1]$ and let $\mu(A)=1$ if $A \in U$ and $\mu(A)=0$ if $A \notin U$.

Comment: @aduh: So you have proved that measurable cardinals are inconsistent. Nice.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I'm sorry, have I misreported something?

Comment: @AsafKaragila Ah I see, Oxtoby's result, as stated, holds for $X$ with cardinality $\aleph_1$. When I wrote the comment I thought we were assuming that $X = [0,1]$ (in which case, we'd need to assume CH to apply the result), but that's not so (a commenter suggested it, but it's not in the OP). Thanks for pointing this out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Such measure does not exist.

> $Theorem:$ Let $μ$ be a nonnegative bounded measure defined on all subsets of a set $S$.Then exists a countable set$C \subseteq S$ such that $μ(S$\ $C)=0$

Now let $X$ be a set and  suppose that exists a measure $μ$  on  $P(X)$ such that $μ(Χ)=1$ and $μ(\{x\})=0, \forall x \in X$.

Then exist a countable set $C \subseteq X$ such that $μ(X$\ $C)=0$

But $C=\{x_1,x_2....\}$ and $μ(C)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty μ(\{x_n\})=0$ thus $μ(X)=μ(Χ$\ $C)+μ(C)=0$ which is a contradiction.

I will also post down to the comments the text ,in which i found this theorem.

Comment: http://www.math.purdue.edu/~branges/measure-problem.pdf

Comment: thanks a lot this answers my question. does this theorem work on every arbitrary set?

Comment: You are welcome..as you see in the statement of the theorem ,it works for every set

Comment: Some hypothesis is missing in the Theorem you mentioned.  As stated, it is false. Counterexample:  Let $S$  be an uncountable set and let $\mu$  be the **counting measure**.  It is clear that $\mu$ is defined on all subsets of $S$, and it is also easy to see that  there is no countable subset $C$ of $S$ such that $\mu(S\setminus C)=0$.

Comment: In the paper in which you found the theorem, the measure are assumed to be **bounded**.  So the theorem actually is: 

$Theorem:$ Let $μ$ be a nonnegative **bounded** measure defined on all subsets of a set $S$.Then exists a countable set$C \subseteq S$ such that $μ(S$\ $C)=0$

Comment: thanks i will edit my answer..thanks for your correction

Comment: If there is a measurable cardinal, then such a measure does exist. In fact, from a measurable cardinal we can construct a universe in which the Lebesgue measure has a total extension (which is not translation invariant, of course). So your answer is certainly incorrect.

Answer (score 3):

At least under some set theoretic assumptions, such set and measure exist. Moreover, the set can be $\Bbb R$ and the measure can be an extension of the Lebesgue measure.

We say that a cardinal $\kappa$ is *measurable* if there is a non-principal ultrafilter $U$ on $\kappa$ which is $\kappa$-additive.

1. The existence of a measurable cardinal is quite stronger than "standard set theory", i.e. $\sf ZFC$, in the sense that from the existence of a measurable cardinal we can prove that $\sf ZFC$ is consistent, and much much more. This means that we cannot prove that measurable cardinals are consistent, unless we start with even stronger hypotheses, but nevertheless the consensus seems to be that measurable cardinals are "probably consistent", as they have been studied extensively for several decades now.
2. If $\kappa$ is the least uncountable cardinal such that $\kappa$ carries a $\sigma$-complete non-principal ultrafilter, then $\kappa$ is in fact a measurable cardinal. This is a non-trivial theorem, but it shows that if you want to strengthen your requirements that the measure is binary, then we already shoot quite high our the set theoretic assumptions.
3. If we assume that $\kappa$ is in fact a measurable cardinal, then we can prove that there is a mathematical universe where $2^{\aleph_0}=\kappa$, and there is a measure $\mu$ on $[0,1]$ which measures *all* subsets and extends the Lebesgue measure. As per the axiom of choice, this $\mu$ is no longer translation invariant, but nevertheless it is $\sigma$-additive.

While I don't know what happens if allow both the measure to be non-binary, and the set to be larger than the reals. But if I were a gambling man, I would guess this is probably as strong a requirement as having a measure cardinal, in terms of consistency assumptions.

---

If you are willing to let go of the axiom of choice, then it is also possible that the Lebesgue measure on $[0,1]$ satisfies these requirements. However, one can see that in order to ensure that the measure is non-zero, one has to ensure that the countable union of countable sets of reals are countable. So some choice is needed, but it is consistent with $\sf DC$, which is a mild form of choice, that the Lebesgue measure in fact measures all the subsets of $[0,1]$.

It should be remarked that this again requires assumptions "going beyond $\sf ZFC$", although significantly weaker than those discussed above. Here a single inaccessible cardinal would suffice.

(If one is willing to allow an extension of the Lebesgue measure, and allows choice to fail, then indeed one can obtain this without any additional consistency assumptions beyond the standard set theory.)